# Database design: user with contact information

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database design question.

In my application, a user has contact information including

- telephone number
- email
- adress line 1
- postal box
- Locality (City)

This is currentl located in a "user" table with the other informations like username, first name, ...

The thing is that a user has to have the same kind of information (telephone, email, ...) but for his company.

It seems redundant to add additional fields to the "user" table. As the data are similar, I could make a "ContactInfo" table with the fields:

- phone
- email
- address
- postal box
- ...

Is it a good idea and how should I do the relation between the "user" table and this "contactInfo" table ?

EDIT: I forgot to say that the company contact information is not obligatory. A user can have no company at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate tables are the right choice.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  foo VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id) );

CREATE TABLE user_contact_info (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  contact_type VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20),
  email VARCHAR(200),
  address VARCHAR(200),
  postal_box VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, user_id) );
```

If your database supports foreign keys, there should be a foreign key from `user_contact_info.user_id` to `users.id`.  `user_contact_info.contact_type` would be set to `work` or `home` or whatever other categories you need.

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to do. It seems to be the right choice

Comment: THe only thing with that is the optional work info. I wonder how to do when a user removes his company information. The line in user_contact_info would be empty then.

Comment: Are you saying that the you want to keep track of the company's contact info?  If so, just add a `companies` table.  If a company can have more than one phone, address, etc, make a `company_contact_info` table like the `user_contact_info` table above.  If you want to associate a `user` to a `company`, make a `user_company` table that supports the many-to-many relationship (with an indicator of the type of relationship: `employee`, `customer`, both?).

Comment: @Marc, if the user deletes their company info, delete the corresponding row in `user_contact_info`.  It won't be blank, it will be gone.

Comment: A user can have only one company in my case. And I have to keep only one number, email etc per company. I was just saying that the company info is not obligatory and that the user can remove the information. I don't want to keep track of it, but if I just update it in the database all the fields will be empty.

Comment: So I basically have to check if there is no information left and delete the row ?

Comment: If user:company is 1:1 and company:user is 1:N, put a `company_id` foreign key reference in the `users` table.  You can then use `ON DELETE SET NULL` to have the database do the NULLing for you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 3):

Anything with a 1:M relationship between the user should be on its own table.  If you only care about the user's primary contact information, then you can get away with keeping it on the User table.

*For example*: If it is acceptable to have two phone numbers (or more) then you will have another table with a foreign key to your users table and the phone number, the phone type, and the contact order priority.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate phone table, a separate email table and a separate address table. People have more than one of all three.